# Overwriting a single byte in a binary file makes it unrecognizable by objdump?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I want to overwrite a single byte in a binary file at a specific `offset`. The value `cval` is an integer.

To do this, I've written the following code:

```
f = open(program, "wb")
f.seek(offset, 0) # absolute
#print(f.read(1))
f.write(bytes([cval]))
f.close()
```

The code works perfectly when reading the byte at `offset`, but writing to this position results in `objdump` cannot recognize the ELF binary.

```
mfo@mfo-Ubuntu:~/llvm-ir-obfuscation/checker$ objdump -dF fac_c
objdump: fac_c: File format not recognized
```

I don't see what I do wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're not writing in some header?

Comment: When I do `f.read(1)`, I read the bit correctly in the `.text` section. However, the write operation somehow messes things up.

Comment: You really should be downvoted for not checking your "unrecognized" file size before posting this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You opened your file with `w` mode, which truncates the file when opening it. So your final file will only consist of the one byte you wrote.

Just open it in update mode:

```
f = open(program, "r+b")
```

and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

See this tutorial on Python File I/O:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm

> **rb+**:  Opens a file for both reading and writing in binary format. The
>   file pointer placed at the beginning of the file.

What confuses you is probably that you think of **rb+** as reading and **wb+** as writing. However, both modes open the file for reading and writing, while the latter also overwrites the file.

Because the latter mode overwrites the file, the ELF binary is effectively destroyed (the headers are gone).